# submit dropdown values htmlunit

Tags: htmlunit

How it is possible to do the following with HTML Unit?

1. Select Value From First Dropdown.
2. According to the selected value in first dropdown, a second Dropdown will generate some values.
3. The user have to select a value from second dropdown.
4. Both the dropdowns are selected and now on the click of checkbox, the form will be submitted using AJAX.